# How to add "custom" directories path to the left bar on Cinnamon File Manager

Tags: cinnamon, nautilus

I have some directories that I access almost all the time and I would like to have a shortcut to them in the File Manager (I think is Nautilus) in the left bar if it's possible.

Look at the following pic:

[image]

I would like to have a custom link saying "Apps" and mapped to `~/Apps` so I can go there in one click, is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

You can press `Ctrl` + `D` to create a bookmark, will appear in a 2nd group below the drives

Comment: Well *that* is not documented well anywhere. I've been struggling to add this for the last half hour and stumbled across this post. I'm using unity  on Ubuntu 17.04 and couldn't figure out why I couldn't drag/get a drive over there. Not even a right click or menu bar option. Thanks